# GitHub commit history doesn't match Visual Studio commit history (GitHub extension)

Tags: git, github, commit

I'm trying to understand why the commit history that I can see in Visual Studio 2017 for a particular git repo doesn't match what is shown as the commit history for the same repo on GitHub.

In particular, I'm looking at the commit history located here:
https://github.com/handruin/spdif-ka/commits/master

As you can see, between March 27 and May 31 there are 9 commits listed.

In Visual Studio I have that repo configured as the upstream remote and I've done a fetch to get fully up-to-date with it. The latest commit identifier matches with the one on GitHub for that branch.

But for some reason, when I do 'View History' on that master branch in Visual Studio, I see only 5 commits between those dates, not 9. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Does anybody know why I'm only seeing 5 of the commits in Visual Studio whereas 9 commits are listed on GitHub?

EDIT: here is a larger screenshot, where I've also included a window showing the configuration of my upstream remote, the one that I'm showing the history for.

[image]

I see that the missing commits are actually present, they're just much further down in the list. So I guess it's more a question of why the presentation of the order is so different between this history window versus what is shown on GitHub. And is there a way to make them display the commits in the same order?

Comment: could you extend you screenshot so the other ends of the graph links are visible

Comment: and better to print those commits with git log --pretty=fuller, so that committer and author times are visible

Comment: I've added an additional screenshot. I guess the question now is more about ordering rather than them being missing completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page I was looking at on GitHub, showing the commits for a particular branch, shows a flat commit list. When viewing the history of that same branch in Visual Studio a graph is shown, with nodes illustrating all of the associated branching and merging activity. That's why the order is different. To see a very similar view in GitHub, it is necessary to click on the 'Insights' tab and then on 'Network'.